# using a second array count unique values in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

There are many posts on counting unique values in arrays, but I want to count the unique values in an array based on a second array. Specifically: I want to count the distinct occurrences within `arr`, but of all the values within `grade`

```
arr = [
  "12D","12D","12D",
  "12C","12C","12C","12C","12C",
  "12B","12B","12B","12B","12B",
  "12B","12B",
  "12A","12A","12A","12A","12A",
  "12A","12A","12A","12A","12A",
  "12A","12A"
]

grade = ["13B", "13A", "12D", "12C", "12B", "12A"]

result = arr.filter(item => grade.includes(item))
  .reduce((acc, val) => {
    acc[val] = acc[val] === undefined ? 1 : acc[val] += 1;
    return acc;
  }, {});
```

## Current Result

My current result does count up the unique occurances

```
{ '12D': 3, '12C': 5, '12B': 7, '12A': 12 }
```

## Desired Output

but I want to include ALL the values within grade inside my final object (and in the order of `grade`]

```
desired_result = {
    '13B': 0,
    '13A': 0,
    '12D': 3,
    '12C': 5,
    '12B': 7,
    '12A': 12
}
```

Is it possible to perform this reduce using a second vector?

Comment: I think some context is missing but if thats the whole thing, I would go at it from another direction, I would first convert the "grade" array to an object with all 0 as a value and key would be the grade from array.
Then run on "arr" and just add the counter where it fits.

Answer (score 1):

You could map grades as entries and take the object as start value of reduce.

```js
const
    array = ["12D", "12D", "12D", "12C", "12C", "12C", "12C", "12C", "12B", "12B", "12B", "12B", "12B", "12B", "12B", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A", "12A"],
    grade = ["13B", "13A", "12D", "12C", "12B", "12A"],
    result = array.reduce(
        (acc, val) => {
            if (val in acc) acc[val]++;
            return acc;
        },
        Object.fromEntries(grade.map(g => [g, 0]))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Not sure if it's critical to OP but doesn't filter out values that aren't in `grade`. Example doesn't have any but real cases may do

Comment: @charlietfl, now it counts only known props.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to start off with the grades and build a frequency table as follows. Then you can invoke `Object.fromEntries()` on the resulting array of array pairs:

```
const result = Object.fromEntries(
    grade.map(grade => [grade, arr.filter(g => g === grade).length])
);
```

**DEMO**

```js
const arr = ["12D","12D","12D","12C","12C","12C","12C","12C","12B","12B","12B","12B","12B","12B","12B","12A","12A","12A","12A","12A","12A","12A","12A","12A","12A","12A","12A"];

const grade = ["13B", "13A", "12D", "12C", "12B", "12A"];

const result = Object.fromEntries(
    grade.map(grade => [grade, arr.filter(g => g === grade).length])
);

console.log( result );
```